# I can't find where I set the zsh PROMPT

Tags: zsh

I've got zsh 5.0 installed via brew on OS X Mountain Lion.

I used something to set up this lovely value for PROMPT:

%B%F{yellow}%K{yellow}%{█▓▒░%}%B%F{white}%K{yellow}%n@%m%b%F{red}%K{yellow}%{░▒▓█%}%b%F{red}%K{black}%{█▓▒░%}%B%F{white}%K{black} %D{%a %b %d} %D{%I:%M:%S%P} 
%}%B%F{yellow}%K{black}%~/%b%f%k

However, there is no setting for PROMPT in my .zshenv, .zshrc, .zlogin, or the files in /etc.

I have a rather vague memory that I might have installed some addon that has something to do with this, but I cannot recall what. None of my . files seem to contain the setting.

is there an option to zsh that will cause it to reveal what it is reading when it starts up?

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be:

```
prompt fire
```

which sets PROMPT.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some zsh sugar (like [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh)) installed. Check for `ZSH=…` in your `.zshrc` and if it’s set it gives you the clue where to find your `PROMPT`.